# Show post based on timing and date

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to display the post from specific category to show on basis of TIME and DATE.

Suppose, i have created a post on Monday 6:00 PM GST. It will show the post only after a week on Monday at the same time, and hides on every other day.
Can anyone help me on this?

```
<div style="float:left;width:100%">
    <?php
        global $post;
        $args = array('category' => 8, 'numberposts' => 4,'orderby' => 'date','order' => 'ASC',);
        $myposts = get_posts( $args );
        foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <?php
        $postDate = strtotime( $post->post_date );
        $todaysDate = time() - (time() % 86400);
        $todayTime = get_field('now_show_time');
        $time= time();
        if ( $postDate >= $todaysDate) : ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="font-size:11px;"><span style="font-weight:bold;color:#afaca5"><?php the_time('n/j'); ?>:</span> <?php the_title_attribute(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

The above code only matching the date, I want to match the TIME and show the post..please help!

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you provide more details to your question? Show us what you have tried so far, so we don't present solutions you already tried and realized aren't effective. Thanks.

Comment: I am building a program schedule page, which will show the user " Now Showing" section. Which will display the post only when the date/time is same.

Comment: Have you thought about using strtotime() http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php this will let you compare two times down to the second.

Comment: To make it more specific, there is a show which broadcast every 6:00 PM on Monday. I want that show to "DISPLAY" only when there is Monday and 6:00 PM and hides it if there is any other day.